# Ios react-native cant deploy to app store getting ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native-ios, info.plist

I am getting from App Store Connect: 
NSContactsUsageDescription and NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription is missing,
But when I am locking in my info.plist I see those properties.

What should I do next? 
Hoo to debug or find where those properties are missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With permission in `ios/[app-name]/Info.plist`

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires contacts access to function properly.</string>
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>App uses Bluetooth to find, connect and communicate with nearby devices. Please grant access.</string>
```

Be careful with `space`, you can check `Info.plist` as a source code

if you target iOS below 13, you also need to add `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`

Comment: it's ok no spaces there
 <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
  <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use your contacts</string>

NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription already there

Comment: Could you send the full description from App Store Connect?

Comment: ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSContactsUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required.

Comment: `If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required`
That mean your code or any other Library or SDKs can use another permission, even if you don't use it, but you still need to provide privacy description.

Comment: I have a lot of them is there a way to find which one causes the problem?